# .htaccess in Angular works only for subfolder

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, routes

I have deployed the app into a Debian 11 Apache server into a folder in `var/www/html`, i.e. `var/www/html/foo`.
Being my first time deploying an Angular app, I've noticed problems with routing and hard refreshing (indeed, a 404 error occurs whenever I try to refresh a page of my app).
My app has several routes, such as:

```
site.com/items
site.com/map
site.com/item/4
...
```

I've read that I need to create an `.htaccess` file in order to fix that, so I've created one and placed it into the root (i.e., `html`).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Being `var/www/html` a shared folder with other apps (e.g. `var/www/html/bar1`, `var/www/html/bar2`) that I don't manage, I've also created other `.htaccess` files with `RewriteEngine Off` and placed them into those app folders in order to avoid issues.

For sake of clarity, this is the tree structure of my folder:

```
var/www/html:.
│   .htaccess
│   ...
│   ...
├───foo (my app)
├───bar1
│   │   .htaccess (RewriteEngine Off)
│   │   ...
└───bar2
        .htaccess (RewriteEngine Off)
        ...
```

Unfortunately this `.htaccess` doesn't seem to work properly. I'm still experiencing hard refresh problems when using `site.com/foo` app.

Now for the "funny" part: for testing purposes I've created another `foo` subfolder inside the `var/www/html/foo` folder that is exactly the copy of the parent folder (minus the `.htaccess`) containing the `dist` of the Angular app. And whenever I access `site.com/foo/foo` the app works as expected (no hard refresh problems); conversely, if I access `site.com/foo` the hard refresh doesn't work anymore.
Again, for the sake of clarity, here's the tree structure.
Notice that I've placed another `.htaccess` inside the parent `foo`.

```
var/www/html/foo:.
│   .htaccess
│   favicon.ico
│   index.html
│   main.js
│   main.js.map
│   polyfills.js
│   polyfills.js.map
│   runtime.js
│   runtime.js.map
│   scripts.js
│   scripts.js.map
│   styles.css
│   styles.css.map
│   vendor.js
│   vendor.js.map
│   
├───assets
│   │   ...
│   ├───img
│   │       ...
│           
└───foo
    │   favicon.ico
    │   index.html
    │   main.js
    │   main.js.map
    │   polyfills.js
    │   polyfills.js.map
    │   runtime.js
    │   runtime.js.map
    │   scripts.js
    │   scripts.js.map
    │   styles.css
    │   styles.css.map
    │   vendor.js
    │   vendor.js.map
    │   
    └───assets
        │   ...  
        ├───img
        │       ...
```

The folders and their contents are absolutely identical, so I'm guessing it has to do with the `.htaccess`.
Any idea on why this happens and how to fix the hard refresh problem in the first `foo` folder? Also, I'd like to move the content of `foo` to the `html` folder, in order to have my app at `mysite.com`. Is it okay to leave the `.htaccess` in the root (i.e. `html`).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you putting your .htaccess for the angular app into `var/www/html/` to begin with, and not into `var/www/html/foo/`?

Comment: I have two `.htaccess`, identical by all means, one in `var/www/html` folder and one in `var/www/html/foo/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, At first I am assuming that you're using Apache/httpd server with all necessary extensions enabled. It's not an issue with Angular itself, but with Apache/.htaccess configuration. Basycally what you need to do, is to configure your http traffic for domain, to always point onto your index.html file.

Please check out this .htaccess file, that you're putting in root (next to index.html) to which domain should be pointed.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If it's not working, then I will recommend to check your Apache configuration and enable mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

as also I would check vhost configuration to make sure

```
AllowOverride all
```

is included

**IMPORTANT!** Remember to restart your Apache server after changes.

Comment: Thank you @lemek. I moved all the `dist` into the root along with the `.htaccess` that you provided me. Strangely enough, I did not restart the server (I won't have root access until Monday), but it seems to works just fine. No more hard refresh errors! Just a quick question though: while the ip with `http://` is perfect, I'm experiencing a Mixed content error using dns with `https://` (indeed, some fetch requests insecure HTTP endpoints but the page is loaded over HTTPS). Does the commented part of your `.htaccess` helps with this or do I have to manually change every url inside my app?

Comment: @friendlynihilist unfortunately the answer is "it depends", and my answer is: `probably no`, my .htaccess is not sufficient to remove mixed content error. You will need to either modify .htaccess to rewrite every call or rewrite all URLS in your application.